# Count objects grouping by field in Java

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list

I have a class Flight and class for Airport which holds collection with several flights.

```
public class Flight {

String flightNumber;            
String departureCity;
String departureCountry;
String departure;
String arrivalCity;
String arrivalCountry;
String arrival;
//etc...}

public class Airport {

String name;
String city;
String country;
LinkedList <Flight> flights;
//etc...}
```

I have a task in university to count the number of flights in one airport for each departureCountry field of Flight class. Is there any algorithm to do that?
I thought to sort the collection somehow by this parameter(departureCountry) but couldn't come up with some clear decision. I will be grateful for your help.

Comment: You could do something like group by departure country in flight and count the flights belong to those groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a neat way using Java 8 streams:

```
import java.util.*;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // I made constructor for departureCountry only to keep it simple
        List<Flight> flights = Arrays.asList(
          new Flight("USA"),
          new Flight("UK"),
          new Flight("CAN"),
          new Flight("USA"),
          new Flight("UK")
        );

        Map<String, Long> flightsPerCountry =
          flights.stream()
                 .collect(groupingBy(Flight::getDepartureCountry, counting()));


        System.out.println(flightsPerCountry);
        // {CAN=1, USA=2, UK=2}
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution! Very unexpected way of cracking this problem :) Although I can't check it out right now cos I have Java 7.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not going to write the whole code here, but just the steps.

- for each airport

  - keep a map of departureCountry to count (i.e. a map<String, Integer>)
  - for each flight in the airport

    - increment the count for the departureCountry in the map
      // that's it, you have the counts now

Sorting is not needed at all given that who just need the count, i.e. essentially grouping for which a map is sufficient as explained in the steps above.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your solution is pretty clear even without code :)